# How to disable CORS only for dev profile in the application-dev.yml file?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, cors

I'm trying to disable CORS, because I'm getting the following error:

> Access to fetch at 'https://localhost:9000/api/foo' from origin 'https://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
> Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FAILED

I want CORS only disabled when the *dev* profile is active. How can I achieve this?

I've already tried the following:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**")
                .allowedOrigins("*")
                .allowedMethods("GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "HEAD")
                .allowCredentials(true)
                .maxAge(3600);
    }
}
```

**Update**: There is another class that I think is related to this problem:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConf extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Bean
    CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
        config.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList(
                "https://example1.com:9000",
                "https://example2.com:9000",
        config.setAllowCredentials(true);
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/api/**", config);
        return source;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you want to allow all origins by using a wildcard in your non-dev profiles?

Comment: @deHaar, I just tried disabling the CORS as an experiment to see if it works at all

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just annotate your config with `@Profile("dev")`:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@Profile("dev")
public class DevWebSecurityConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**")
                .allowedOrigins("*")
                .allowedMethods("GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "HEAD")
                .allowCredentials(true)
                .maxAge(3600);
    }
}
```

Test:

```java
class DevWebSecurityConfigTestConfigurationTest {

    private static final ApplicationContextRunner runner = new ApplicationContextRunner()
            .withConfiguration(AutoConfigurations.of(DevWebSecurityConfig.class));

    @Test
    void devProfileSet_devWebSecurityConfigActive() {
     runner.withPropertyValues("spring.profiles.active=dev")
             .run(context -> assertThat(context).hasSingleBean(DevWebSecurityConfig.class));
    }

    @ParameterizedTest
    @ValueSource(strings = {"default", "prod"})
    void devProfileNotSet_devWebSecurityConfigNotActive(final String profile) {
     runner.withPropertyValues("spring.profiles.active=" + profile)
             .run(context -> assertThat(context).doesNotHaveBean(DevWebSecurityConfig.class));
    }
}
```

**Update**
You added a `CorsConfigurationSource` bean to your example code. For this approach, you could declare two beans depending on the profile:

```java
    @Profile("!dev")
    @Bean
    CorsConfigurationSource defaultCorsConfigurationSource() {
        CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
        config.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList(
                "https://example1.com:9000",
                "https://example2.com:9000");
        config.setAllowCredentials(true);
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/api/**", config);
        return source;
    }


    @Profile("dev")
    @Bean
    CorsConfigurationSource devCorsConfigurationSource() {
        CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
        config.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("https://localhost.com:3000");
        config.setAllowCredentials(true);
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/api/**", config);
        return source;
    }
```

The example test can be adapted in the way that you can also use the bean name (`devCorsConfigurationSource`, `defaultCorsConfigurationSource`) for asserting whether a bean is present or not.

You should however stick to one way: either use the [`addCorsMappings` of the `WebMvcConfigurer`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/web.html#mvc-cors-global-java) to configure it or with the [`CorsConfigurationSource` bean and the `.cors(withDefaults())` setting on the `HttpSecurity`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/integrations/cors.html).

Comment: I'm still getting the same error. Could it be a problem if there is an another `WebConfig` class without the `@EnableWebMvc` and `@Profile("dev")` annotations? It overrides `addResourceHandlers` and `addViewControllers` methods

Comment: Yes, try annotating it with `@Order(1)`

Comment: It's still not working. I tried annotating class `WebConfig` with `@Order(1)` and the other `WebConfig` class with `@Order(2)` and vica versa. I updated my question